# how to place flowplayer block/window for video playing on right hand side of the page

Tags: html

HI Everyone

I am using flowplayer for uploading videos so that client can play them.I am working on localhost.Now problem is that by default flowplayer comes in left hand side of the page.I want it to align on right hand side.I know somewhere align="right" or something like this will be used but i dont know where i have to put this word.I have tried a lot have done google have serched in flowplayer site have read their documentation but problem is not solved can anybody help me in this matter,,,

```
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="flowplayer-3.1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>


in <body>

<a 
    href="video.flv" 
    style="display:block;width:250px;height:200px;align:right;" 
    id="player">
</a>


<script language="JavaScript">
flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf" , { clip: { autoPlay : false, autoBuffering: true}});  //create a object of clip name
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#player {float: right};`

However that may have other implications on your layout so alternatively you could use the params to flowplayer:

`flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.1.5.swf" , { clip: { autoPlay : false, autoBuffering: true}}, {align: 'right'});`

Comment: no sir it is not working i have tried it..I am not getting what to do .Problem is not difficult but dont know how it will be used

Comment: where i should put this #player {float: right}; i tried along with clip section but is it not working there and morever my play is not displaying after this

Comment: i found solution...

in css part i have to use relative;left:1054 by this dimension my player will shift to right